# How to use nested SELECT statements with IN operator in SQL (JPA)?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa

I want to use the following SQL query in my java class:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE attribute1 IN (
  SELECT attribute1
  FROM table2
  WHERE attribute2 = c
)
```

Here `table1` and `table2` are two entities having the *common column* `attribute1`.

How to get the result of this query as a List of type `table1`?

Comment: Try with `table2.attribute1`

Comment: If you use this SQL in SQL-developer, what was your actual result, and what did you expect it to be? Please [edit] your post with some example output. So we now your current start and the desired goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the result as List of type table1. 
A table is a collection of columns. A Java List can contain only a collection of one column. 
Imagine `table1` contains 5 columns of different data types (say INTEGER, VARCHAR2, INTEGER, VARCHAR2, VARCHAR2). Your query will return a `ResultSet` containing all these values.
Now, you are expecting a simple List to store all these values. It is not correct. 
If you want to store all values of a particular column, then you can do it as shown below.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE attribute1 IN (SELECT attribute1 FROM table2 WHERE attribute2 = c)");
List<String> attr = new ArrayList<String>();

while (rs.next()) {
    attr.add(rs.getString("attribute1"));
}
```

If you wish to obtain values of different column, then use `rs.getXXX("<column_name");` to fetch its details. Note: Replace getXXX with appropriate method based on datatype of the column. For example, getString() for VARCHAR, getInt() for INTEGER etc.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.